# how to customize colorbar location for bar chart in subplot?

Tags: python, plotly

I have 2 subplot and I am using go.Figure() instead of plotly express, one is heatmap, the other is bar chart, the bar chat is created below so it has a color bar as well. now I have 2 colorbars one for heatmap one for bar chat. How do I change color bar location of bar chart like height, anchor point etc? I tried goolging it for a long time and I never found a solution.

Here is what I did for bar chart

```
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.0,
                    specs=[[{"secondary_y": False}],[{"secondary_y": True}]],
                    subplot_titles=(figuretitle,
                    row_width=[0.25,0.75],  # from bottom to up
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                   )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
        x=time_plot_location_list,   # time   # single data have to use list [data]
        y=slope_list_horner,  # it is a series
      marker=dict(color=slope_list_horner,colorscale="Bluered_r",showscale=True,colorbar=dict(title="Horner")),
        text=slope_list_horner,
        texttemplate='%{y:.2f}',
        hovertemplate='Horner:%{y:.2f}',
        ),
        row=row,
        col=1,
                 )
```

Comment: I got it now, colorbar of bar chart belong to marker, so change colorbar parameter inside bar chart will work, like this: marker=dict(color=slope_list_horner,colorscale="Bluered_r",showscale=True,
                    colorbar={'title':"Horner",'yanchor':'bottom','y':0.01,'len':0.25,'xanchor':'left','x':0.98})

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to improve the current situation: you want to fix the overlapping of the two color bars?